# How to silence "Disk Utility" "A hard disk is reporting health problems"

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, smart, smartctl

I'm working on repairing a raid member,
and I know I have a bad disk.  This dialog
appears by the hundreds (a new crop is minted every time
anything touches anything related to a mount, so closing them does no good):

[image: Disk Utility / Hard Disk Problems Detected / A hard disk is reporting health problems.]

Check, got it.  How can I make this go away?
The specific system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: The real question here is: why do you have Xorg on your server?

Comment: This one's got a head: some do.

Comment: Well, my servers have heads as well. They're just text consoles, though, and that's all that a linux server should ever have. I posted an answer - hopefully it's helpful.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [Disabling SMART Disk Utility Warning Message](http://askubuntu.com/q/38281/74792) and [How to stop Ubuntu 9.10 from showing hard disk failing notification?](http://superuser.com/q/76781/2357).

Comment: You're right.  I'll close it.

Comment: This question is a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/q/38281/74792

Answer (score 1):

How to silence that messages box?

I give you two alternatives:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get yourself to a text console and then carry on with your RAID recovery.
2. SSH into the server from your workstation.

Honestly, those are your options.

As I inferred above, Xorg/Gnome/KDE/whatever have *no* place on a linux server. Even the likes of Microsoft have (finally) figured that servers and GUIs are not good bedfellows, and are racing as quickly as possible to strip out as many GUI elements as possible from their server operating systems. If you have an X11 application that you **need** to run (I see this frequently with commercial linux backup packages. Symantec Netbackup and the like), do so via X11 forwarding, not on the console itself.

You likely don't want to hear this answer, but I give it nonetheless, as it's the *right* answer.